# R: Select rows (by group) based on certain conditions being met

Tags: r, conditional-statements

```
ID      Date1       Date2       Date3
1111    4/6/2016    NA          5/1/2016
1111    4/6/2016    3/31/2016   NA
1111    4/6/2016    4/2/2016    3/29/2016
1112    4/17/2016   4/29/2016   6/2/2016
1112    4/17/2016   5/1/2016    5/16/2016
1112    4/17/2016   NA          2/1/2016
1113    4/6/2016    3/4/2016    5/12/2016
1113    4/6/2016    4/4/2016    2/16/2016
1114    5/2/2016    4/20/2016   5/29/2016
1114    5/2/2016    4/30/2016   5/21/2016
1115    3/31/2016   2/3/2016    2/2/2016
1115    3/31/2016   2/5/2016    2/4/2016
```

Given the above data set, I want to select the MAX (most recent) value from Date3 and the MIN (oldest) value from Date2 per ID, given that:

At least one value in Date2 is less (older) than Date1 and one value in Date3 is more (newer) than Date1 PER ID.

I would want the following to be returned:

```
1111    4/6/2016    3/31/2016   5/1/2016
1113    4/6/2016    3/4/2016    5/12/2016
1114    5/2/2016    4/20/2016   5/29/2016
```

(1112 would not be returned because neither value in Date2 is less than Date1, and 1115 would not be returned because neither value in Date3 is greater than Date1).

I've been working on this for quite some time (I'm a novice coder), so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in two steps. First, get the set of IDs that match your criteria:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
selected_ids <- data %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarize(PassD1vD2=any(na.omit(Date2 < Date1)),
              PassD1vD3=any(na.omit(Date3 > Date1))) %>%
    filter(PassD1vD2 & PassD1vD3) %$% ID %>% unique
```

Then select the group min & max:

```
filtered_data <- data %>% 
    filter(ID %in% selected_ids) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarize(Date1=Date1[1], minD2=min(Date2, na.rm=TRUE), maxD3=max(Date3, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: Ryan, you were absolutely right about the issues with the code below.  Your code provides the actual information that I was looking for.  Thanks for noticing the issue and thanks for the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use dplyr library try this:

```
library(dplyr)
filtered_data <- data %>% filter(Date2 < Date1 & Date3 > Date1) %>%
 group_by(ID, Date1) %>% 
 summarize(minD2 = min(Date2, na.rm = T), maxD3 = max(D3, na.rm = T)
```

That should give you desired data frame.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  From a cursory glance, this does provide the initial data frame I'm looking for (I got similar results using much less efficient code).  I do need to meet the condition listed above (listed under "given that"), however, which is what I've really struggled with.  Any advice on that?

Comment: That is why I have filter(Date2 < Date1 & Date3 > Date1) that makes sure you have only such records that Date2 < date1 and date 3 > date 1. Isn't it what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part the first time.  This works and is much simpler than what I was working through on my own.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help:)

Comment: That filtering criterion is not necessarily correct given the description in the original question. You're requiring that `Date2 < Date1` and `Date3 > Date1` occur on the same row, whereas the criterion as written says that they each only need to occur in any row within a given ID, not necessarily the same row.

Comment: Huh.. I guess I read it wrong. Then your solution is more correct.